# oauth2 getting Faraday::TimeoutError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

i am using the oauth2 gem

my code is

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('xyz', '123', :site => "http://localhost:3000")
access_token = client.password.get_token(params[:person][:email], params[:person][:password])
```

i am getting the client.

but while 'client.password.get_token' request for token i am getting Faraday::TimeoutError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this because I'm assuming you don't have a threadsafe application server running the rails application.

The problem here is that you're trying to create a new request (call it child) from within a request (call it parent), so until the parent request is complete the child request is not going to respond.

You can certainly test this from the rails console and see it working without issues.  In order to make this work, you could run another instance of your application on a different port say `3001` then do:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('xyz', '123', :site => "http://localhost:3001")
```